# crear un else despues de un while?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

hola es posible crear un else despues de while ?
quiero hacer un else que tire un mensaje simple que diga que el piloto no fue encontrado
este es mi código :

```
<?php 
    
    if(isset ($_GET['enviar'])) {
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE rut = '$busqueda'");

        while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
            echo '<div style="font-size:1.35em;color:black;font-weight:bold">DATOS DEL PILOTO:
            </div>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'RUT: ';
            echo $row ['rut'].'<br>';
            echo 'Numero de Piloto: ';
            echo $row ['nroPiloto'].'<br>';
            echo 'Nombre: ';
            echo $row ['nombre'].'<br>';
            echo '<div style="font-size:1.25em;color:green;font-weight:bold">PILOTO REGISTRADO! </div>';
        }  
     
    }
```

?>

Comment: Si bien los ciclos funcionan con condiciones, no son estructuras específicamente de decisión. Además de que el else se usa como alternativa del if si la condición no se cumple. Por tanto no tiene sentido usar un else sin un if previo.

Comment: @mateo el if esta usado previamente al principio del código

Comment: Disculpa. Entendí que querías conectar el else con el while. Claro que es posible si te refieres a eso. Tal como en el ejemplo que ofrece la documentación de PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.else.php

Answer (score 1):

Bueno para iniciar la restructuraría de la siguiente manera

```
<?php 
    
    if(isset ($_GET['enviar'])) {
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE rut = '$busqueda'");
        //capturo la respuesta
        $response = $consulta->fetch_array();

        //obtengo el tamaño
        $tamanio = sizeof($response);

        //valido
        if($tamanio == 0){
          echo 'Piloto no fue encontrado';
        } else {
          while ($row = $response) {
            echo '<div style="font-size:1.35em;color:black;font-weight:bold">DATOS DEL PILOTO:
            </div>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'RUT: ';
            echo $row ['rut'].'<br>';
            echo 'Numero de Piloto: ';
            echo $row ['nroPiloto'].'<br>';
            echo 'Nombre: ';
            echo $row ['nombre'].'<br>';
            echo '<div style="font-size:1.25em;color:green;font-weight:bold">PILOTO REGISTRADO! </div>';
          }  
        }
     
    }
```

Espero que te dé una idea del resultado que intentas buscar. Saludos

Comment: Saludos, Si te ayudó la respuesta por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada